# Boton de confirmar "eliminar" en CRUD

Tags: javascript, datatables, sweetalert2

Buenas tardes,

Tengo un código que funciona con una id="confirm" para que tengas que confirmar antes de eliminar un registro de un CRUD usando datatables.

El problema reside en que ya que es un crud, no puede funcionar con ID's ya que habría varios elementos con la misma ID, por lo que tendría que usar una clase en vez de un ID, pero al probarlo no llega a funcionar.

¿Alguien podría decirme que he hecho mal?

**Código Javascript**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".confirm").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var linkURL = $(this).attr("href");
      warnBeforeRedirect(linkURL);
    });

    function warnBeforeRedirect(linkURL) {
      swal({
        title: "¿Estas segur<?php get_Genero($_SESSION['CBSGenero']); ?>?",
        text: "Una vez borrado el usuario, no podrá ser recuperado.",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
      }).then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        if (result.value) {
           window.location.href = linkURL;
        }
      });
    }
    </script>
```

**Código HTML**

```
<tbody id="tBody">
    <?php 
        $query = $user->getUsers();
        foreach($query as $u) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $u['IDUser']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $u['Nombre'] ." ". $u['Apellidos']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $u['Email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $u['Created']; ?></td>
        <td><?php 
            if ($u['Activacion'] == 1) {
                ?> <span class="labelon"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on" aria-hidden="true"></i> Activado</span> <?php
            } else {
                ?> <span class="labeloff"><i class="fa fa-toggle-off" aria-hidden="true"></i> Inactivo</span> <?php
            }

        ?></td>
        <td><?php 
            if ($u['Online'] == "1") {
                ?> <span class="labelon">Online</span> <?php
            } else {
                ?> <span class="labeloff">Offline</span> <?php
            }

        ?></td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn green-jungle dropdown-toggle btn-xs">Acciones</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn green-jungle dropdown-toggle btn-xs" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $CRDomain; ?>profile?user=<?php echo $u['IDUser']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> Ver Perfil </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <?php if($u['Activacion'] == 1): ?>
                        <a href="../assets/controllers/users.php?action=desactivaruser&userid=<?php echo $u['IDUser']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-toggle-off" aria-hidden="true"></i> Desactivar </a>
                        <?php elseif($u['Activacion'] == 0): ?>
                        <a href="../assets/controllers/users.php?action=activaruser&userid=<?php echo $u['IDUser']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on" aria-hidden="true"></i> Activar </a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Editar </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="../assets/controllers/users.php?action=eliminaruser&userid=<?php echo $u['IDUser']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Eliminar </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="confirm" href="usuarios"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Confirm </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Permisos</li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> Ver o Editar </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: A que te referis con varios elementos con el mismo ID? elementos de donde? de la base de datos? si fuera asi, la DB estaria mal.

Comment: Ok, el problema es php o el framework que estas usando? me parece que esta mal tagueada la pregunta, por eso. deberia ser js?

Comment: ok , entonces me retiro ;) veo php, CRUD, id, busco el query y no lo encuentro, hay 3 lineas de php.. los tags son muy importantes...

Comment: y que es lo que ya no funciona? no me queda claro...cual es el comportamiento después de cambiar id por class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una solución podría ser:

- Modificar el selector de `JS` para que busque los *"botones"* `Eliminar`  por una clase (por ejemplo: `confirmDelete`) y no por un `id`.
- Modificar el `markup` (`HTML`) para asignarle a los botones `Eliminar` una `class` para identificarlos y no un `id`

### Ejemplo:

**JS:**
Podemos usar [`event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) y así por mas que los elementos sean creados dinámicamente por `DataTable`, el evento aún sera detectado. Entonces nos suscribimos al evento `click` del documento que sea hayan realizado sobre un `<a>` con class `confirmDelete`. Es decir:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.confirmDelete', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var linkURL = $(this).attr("href");
  warnBeforeRedirect(linkURL);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<li>
   <a class="confirmDelete" href="../assets/controllers/users.php?action=eliminaruser&userid=<?php echo $u['IDUser']; ?>">
     <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     Eliminar
   </a>
</li>
```

### Demo:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a.confirmDelete', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the href from redirecting directly
  var linkURL = $(this).attr("href");
  warnBeforeRedirect(linkURL);
});

function warnBeforeRedirect(linkURL) {
  swal({
    title: "Leave this site?",
    text: "If you click 'OK', you will be redirected to " + linkURL,
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
  }).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    if (result.value) {
      window.location.href = linkURL;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.0.9/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Google</td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="confirmDelete" href="https://google.com">
            <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Eliminar
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Yahoo!</td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="confirmDelete" href="https://yahoo.com">
            <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Eliminar
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: He sido estupido otra vez y al hacer la prueba cambiando el código para usar clases en vez de ID no funcionaba pero era un error de sintaxis, perdona. Ya funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias por la ayuda! te marco la respuesta correcta.